# Can a T-SQL stored procedure select a value from a sub-select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wanna make a stored procedure which shall copy an item from a table and the subitems from the dependent tables.
In my example i have a table called "Instance" which has the key "InstanceID" and has multiple subitems in the table "CustomField".
On its part "CustomField" has multiple subitems in the table "CustomFieldData" joined by the key field "CustomFieldID".

So i made a stored procedure to copy the entries from CustomField and CustomFieldData, which runs after the stored procedure which copies the instance and Returns the new InstanceID.
The first part - the copying of CustomField works.
But then comes the part with the copy of CustomFieldData.
Here i want to use in the INSERT a value (=customfieldidentity) from the following sub-select.
Is this possible?
The actual name customfieldidentity doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

```
USE OneWhoIsWho;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_CopyCustomFieldsToInstance') IS NULL -- Check if SP Exists
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CopyCustomFieldsToInstance AS SET NOCOUNT ON;') -- Create dummy/empty SP
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CopyCustomFieldsToInstance
@instanceId int,
@newInstanceId int
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

    BEGIN TRY

    -- Copy custom fields
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomField]
        ([InstanceID]
        ,[iFieldType]
        ,[iFieldPosition]
        ,[iVisibility]
        ,[txtGUIDescription])
    SELECT
        @newInstanceId
        ,[iFieldType]
        ,[iFieldPosition]
        ,[iVisibility]
        ,[txtGUIDescription]
    FROM [dbo].[CustomField]
    WHERE [dbo].[CustomField].[InstanceID]=@instanceId

    -- Copy custom field data
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomFieldData]
        ([CustomFieldID]
        ,[txtCustomFieldData])
    SELECT
        customfieldidentity
        ,[txtCustomFieldData]
    FROM dbo.CustomFieldData
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT [CustomFieldID] AS customfieldidentity
                ,[InstanceID]
                ,[iFieldType]
                ,[iFieldPosition]
                ,[iVisibility]
                ,[txtGUIDescription]
        FROM [dbo].[CustomField]
        WHERE dbo.CustomField.InstanceID = @newInstanceId)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
    END CATCH
END;
GO
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work??". Also, you have what I call the try-squelch anti-pattern in here. If you encounter an error you simply roll back the transaction. Unless you log the error or somehow inform the system or user that something went wrong you will never know it failed. You also really should avoid the sp_ prefix (or avoid prefixes entirely). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that i can't execute that Stored Procedure because i want to get the column customfieldidentity from the sub-select.

Comment: no you can't use the field in your EXISTS statement in your INSERT

Comment: there's not an easy way to do what you're wanting to do unless you have a column that can join the new `CustomField` to the old `CustomField` like a guid column.   you might need a cursor here to get the `CustomFieldID` after each insert into `CustomField` and insert the `CustomFieldData` after each `CustomField` insert

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I have realized meanwhile that i need a Cursor and a Fetch. I will post the solution when it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.
In my case i have to loop with a cursor and call other stored procedures, which add a single entry to the actual keys within the loop.

Per example:
I wanna copy an instance from the table "Instance".
An instance has multiple custom fields in the table "CustomField".
At first i copy the instance by the given ID of the selected instance:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CopyInstance]
@instanceId int,
@txtInstanceDescription nvarchar(100),
@iHidden int,
@newInstanceId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TranCopyInstance

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Inserts a new instance with the given data
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Instance]
            ([txtInstanceDescription]
            ,[iHidden])
        VALUES
            (@txtInstanceDescription
            ,@iHidden)

        -- Gets the InstanceID of the new instance
        SELECT @newInstanceId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        SELECT @newInstanceId AS InstanceID

        -- Tries to copy the customfields which belong to the original instance
        EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_CopyCustomFields] @instanceId, @newInstanceId

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TranCopyInstance
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TranCopyInstance
    END CATCH
END;
```

As You can see, i call after the copying of the instance the stored procedure sp_CopyCustomFields to copy the entries from the table "CustomField" which belong to the original instance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CopyCustomFields]
@instanceId int,
@newInstanceId int
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomFields

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE customFieldCursor CURSOR
        FOR
        SELECT [dbo].[CustomField].[CustomFieldID]
        FROM [dbo].[CustomField]
        WHERE [dbo].[CustomField].[InstanceID] = @instanceId

        DECLARE @customFieldId int

        -- Loops through all custom fields with the old InstanceID and makes a copy
        OPEN customFieldCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM customFieldCursor INTO @customFieldId
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_CopyCustomField] @instanceId, @newInstanceId, @customFieldId
            FETCH NEXT FROM customFieldCursor INTO @customFieldId
        END
        CLOSE customFieldCursor
        DEALLOCATE customFieldCursor

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomFields
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomFields
    END CATCH
END;
```

Here i look for all entries in the table with the original InstanceID and then i copy each entry with the stored procedure sp_CopyCustomField.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CopyCustomField]
@instanceId int,
@newInstanceId int,
@customFieldId int
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomField

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Placeholder for the new CustomFieldID from the new row after the copy action
        DECLARE @newCustomFieldId int

        -- Makes a copy of the customfield with the old InstanceID and the CustomFieldID
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomField]
            ([InstanceID]
            ,[iFieldType]
            ,[iFieldPosition]
            ,[iVisibility]
            ,[txtGUIDescription])
        SELECT
            @newInstanceId
            ,[iFieldType]
            ,[iFieldPosition]
            ,[iVisibility]
            ,[txtGUIDescription]
        FROM [dbo].[CustomField]
        WHERE [dbo].[CustomField].[InstanceID] = @instanceId
        AND [dbo].[CustomField].[CustomFieldID] = @customFieldId

        -- Finds out the new CustomFieldID
        SELECT @newCustomFieldId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        SELECT @newCustomFieldId AS CustomFieldID

        -- Loops through all custom lists with the old CustomFieldID and makes a copy
        DECLARE customListCursor CURSOR
        FOR
        SELECT [dbo].[CustomList].[CustomListID]
        FROM [dbo].[CustomList]
        WHERE [dbo].[CustomList].[CustomFieldID] = @customFieldId

        DECLARE @customListId int

        OPEN customListCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM customListCursor INTO @customListId
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_CopyCustomList] @customFieldId, @newCustomFieldId, @customListId
            FETCH NEXT FROM customListCursor INTO @customListId
        END
        CLOSE customListCursor
        DEALLOCATE customListCursor

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomField
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TranCopyCustomField
    END CATCH
END;
```

Comment: I would avoid loops at any cost.  I'm not entirely sure of what you are after, but since you use customfieldidentity, in the INSERT, you can add an OUTPUT clause.  Capture the INSERTED.customfieldidentity into a new @Table which you can process after the INSERT.

Comment: The problem is that i wanna copy a certain instance item from the table "Instance" which has multiple customfields (which i have to copy too). Each customfield has multiple customlists and each customlist multiple customlistitems.

Answer (score 2):

Any data inside a sub-query which is being used for EXISTS operator like `EXISTS (Sub-Query)` is not visible for the outer query.

The exists operator only check for the existence of a row/record and returns `True` or `False` it does not actually return any data. You will need to do a `JOIN` instead of an `EXISTS` in the following query .

```
-- Copy custom field data
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomFieldData]
    ([CustomFieldID]
    ,[txtCustomFieldData])
SELECT
    customfieldidentity
    ,[txtCustomFieldData]
FROM dbo.CustomFieldData
WHERE EXISTS             --<-- Replace this with a join 
    (SELECT [CustomFieldID] AS customfieldidentity
            ,[InstanceID]
            ,[iFieldType]
            ,[iFieldPosition]
            ,[iVisibility]
            ,[txtGUIDescription]
    FROM [dbo].[CustomField]
    WHERE dbo.CustomField.InstanceID = @newInstanceId)
```